# Why is python not pythoning

Tags: python, conditional-statements

```
print("Hello, this is my first mini-game. Let's test it out")

character = input("Please choose your gender (male, female): ")
age = input("Please choose your age (child, teen boomer): ")
hobby = input("Please choose your hobby(gaming, school, sport): ")

if (character != "male") or ("female") and (age != "child") or ("teen") or ("boomer") and (hobby != "gaming") or ("school") or ("sport"):
    print("Invalid options")
else:
    print("Beautiful choices you are now a {0} that is a {1} and likes {2}".format(character, age, hobby))
```

This is my code

When I choose the options: male, child and sport it showed invalid options, why??

Comment: `(character != "male") or ("female")` does not do what you think it does and there is no reasonable way that it would ever work, especially given how you set the `(...)`.

Comment: because python is pythoning.

Comment: Specifically what's happening in this case... `"female"` is truthy, `"teen"` is truthy, and `"school"` is truthy, so the `if` condition is hard-coded to *always* be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in the way you check the options.

Firstly how you check if a variable has value in a list:

```py
(character != "male") or ("female")
```

This is incorrect, the first part `(character != "male")` correctly checks if the value of character is not male, the second part (`("female")`) though checks the truth value of just the string "female", this will always be true. Also the two conditions should be evaluated with and `end` (you want to error if character is neither)

To do this check you should do

```py
(character != "male") or (character != "female")
```

Also python provides a more elegant solution:

```py
character not in ("male", "female")
```

The second thing is how you put the different conditions together. You are chaining with the `and` operator but you want to error if any of the three values have wrong choiches so you should use `or`

The whole code would become:

```py
print("Hello, this is my first mini-game. Let's test it out")

character = input("Please choose your gender (male, female): ")
age = input("Please choose your age (child, teen boomer): ")
hobby = input("Please choose your hobby(gaming, school, sport): ")

if character not in ("male", "female") or age not in ("child", "teen", "boomer") or hobby not in ("gaming", "school", "sport"):
    print("Invalid options")
else:
    print("Beautiful choices you are now a {0} that is a {1} and likes {2}".format(character, age, hobby))
```